# What causes this odd behaviour with .length in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting some odd behaviour with the .length property in JS, just wondering if someone could clarify as to why I am getting the results that I am doing.

**This doesn't work:**

```
var ticketsProductName = $.trim($('#ticketsProductName').val());
if (ticketsProductName.length <= 5) {
    // Do error stuff
}
```

ticketsProductName.length returns undefined and thus the statement fails every time.

But...

**This does work:**

```
if ($.trim($('#ticketsProductName').val()).length <= 5) {
    // Do error stuff
}
```

And yields the desired result.

Could someone please explain as to why I can place the trimmed value of #ticketsProductName into the ticketsProductName variable but not call .length on it later? or am I missing something really darn obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the object?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I don't think that can actually happen.

Comment: [unable to reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/tuf2twgv/)

Comment: `val` always returns a string, and a string always have a length, even if it's zero, so I don't think that can actually happen either.

Comment: Your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/jn1roqhj/ You must have a typo in your "original" code.

Comment: So, I was having this issue for hours yesterday. Nothing I could do would change the fact that the above happens. **But**, as is with these things, I've just come to it today - **without modifications** - and it works fine. It *seems* like it must have been caching, although I ruled that out as: I had caching disabled (dev tools, and they were open) and other changes in the code were being pushed just fine. I don't know, probably just a tired case of pebcak.

Thanks for all the help! Greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @Othyn: I've experienced cache related issues with various browsers that has nothing to do with browser caching. Sometimes it's the dev tools/console that's caching. In such cases clearing cache doesn't help. The only way to solve it is to quit the browser and restart from fresh (yes, quit, not just close the current window - close ALL windows)

Answer (score 1):

The statements are equivalent, any mistakes must happen in the code besides this example. If I were to guess I'd say the selector returns nothing and val() is invalid.